# DXLExporter is not exporting the design element sin Xpage?

Tags: lotus-notes, xpages, lotusscript

```
    **I am using the following code,**


    var db=session.getCurrentDatabase()
    var nc:NotesNoteCollection=db.createNoteCollection(true);
    nc.selectAllDesignElements(true);
    nc.buildCollection()
    var filename = "d:\\dxl\\xpDXL.dxl";
    var stream:NotesStream=session.createStream()
    if (stream.open(filename)) {
            stream.truncate(); // Any existing file is erased
            var exporter:NotesDxlExporter = session.createDxlExporter();
            stream.writeText(exporter.exportDxl(db))
    }
```

**     It is not exporting the designelements. But in DXL, It has the documentcollections.**

Comment: Your question appears to be truncated. I recommend editing it to ensure that all the pertinent information displays correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The XPages design elements in DXL are a headache to use. You are better off using the import/export plug-in from OpenNTF. It uses the Eclipse VFS to go after data in native format. So images are images, forms are DXL and XPages are their source. The plug-in contains the source code, so you can see how it is done.
The other option is to link a NSF to an onDisk project (the step necessary for version control) and just look inside the directory.
XPages design elements are a little problematic if you want to deal with them outside of designer: if you inject the source somewhere else you lack the compiled Java. If you are looking at documentation or variation management Designer and VFS (Virtual File System, Java Interface IResource) is our best bet

Comment: Thanks, But I can get the design elements by using getFirstNoteID()... Like  -- Default -- ForLearn
 --  -- WEB-INF/xsp.properties -- .classpath -- build.properties -- plugin.xml -- .project -- vwFirst -- xpLearnJava.xsp -- WEB-INF/faces-config.xml -- xpExcel.xsp -- etc., sorry It is extending to one page. But I can not find the exact reason why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a NotesNoteCollection called nc but you end up exporting db. So change `stream.writeText(exporter.exportDxl(db))` to:

```
stream.writeText(exporter.exportDxl(nc))
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I have tried that also. But the result is same.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is an security issue: You need at least designer access to your database to get  design elements in a DXL export via XPage.

Even public access elements are **not** exported.

Hope this helps
Sven

Comment: But the thing is I have written a DXL code in Lotus script agent and It is exporting well. But in XPage button event, It does not.

Comment: Are you logged on to your XPages application? Or accessing it f.e. locally as Anonymous?

Comment: I have logged in with my user name only. I am manager of this database. Mainly I created this database. \

Comment: Is the "Maximum Internet name and password" setting of your ACL set to Manager" or "Designer? Normally it is set to "Editor"... What if you test your XPage in the Notes Client?

Comment: Nice point, Thanks After set this to manager,Again output remains the same